# Как выполнить запрос на сервер при изменении значения input

Tags: html, ajax

Можно ли выполнить запрос к файлу на сервере, когда закончил вводить значения в `input`? Я делаю следующее:

```
<input class="add" name="add" type="text" placeholder="Add title" onchange="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/add.php">
```

Но не работает. Как мне сделать это?

Comment: используйте ajax

Comment: @XelaNimed кстати ваша правка очень неаккуратная, автор вопроса ничего не писал про запрос на сервер — если судить по исходной формулировке вопроса, автор, возможно, не очень понимает, как работает интернет, и про запросы ничего не знает, а такая правка без объяснений может случайно даже навредить

Comment: @andreymal судя по формулировке вопроса автор впервые столкнулся с такой задачей и поэтому не смог использовать специализированные термины. Заголовок вопроса был изменён для более общего описания задачи и лучшей индексации/поиска. Метка PHP была удалена, как не относящаяся к сути вопроса.

Comment: @XelaNimed многие почему-то думают, что при вставке php-кода внутрь js-обработчика какого-нибудь события он выполнится только при запуске этого js-обработчика, причём без каких-либо ajax-запросов, поэтому скорее всего php имеет прямое отношение к сути вопроса и здесь тоже

Answer (score 1):

При использовании [jQuery](https://jquery.com) это можно очень легко реализовать:

```html
<input id="idIdentifier" name="idIdentifier" type="text" />
```

```js
var changeTimer = false,
    timeout = 300,
    events = "change keyup",
    url = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/add.php";

    $("#idIdentifier").on(events, function () {

        if (changeTimer !== false) {
            clearTimeout(changeTimer);
        }

        changeTimer = setTimeout(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        you: data,
                        is: here
                    },
                    success: function (/*Anything*/ data, /*String*/ textStatus, /*jqXHR*/ jqXHR) {
                        console.info(
                            "data: %o, textStatus: %o, jqXHR: %o",
                            data,
                            textStatus,
                            jqXHR
                        );
                    },
                    error: funtion(/*jqXHR*/ jqXHR, /*String*/ textStatus, /*String*/ errorThrown) {
                        console.error(
                            "jqXHR: %o, textStatus: %o, errorThrown: %o",
                            jqXHR,
                            textStatus,
                            errorThrown
                        );
                    }
                });

                changeTimer = false;

            }, timeout);
    });
```

Скрипт подписывается на события `change` и `keyup` и при их наступлении проверяет прошло ли с последнего события время указанное в `timeout` (иначе мы бы отправляли запрос каждый раз при изменении содержимого), если указанное время прошло, то выполняется AJAX POST запрос по адресу, указанному в переменной `url`.

- в переменную `events` вы можете добавить необходимые события разделяя их пробелом;
- `#idIdentifier` - это селектор, который указывает на элемент с `id="idIdentifier"`;

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com)
- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: Вы прям вернули мой 2007-й) Почитайте про событие input и про Fetch API, с ними всё это можно реализовать ещё проще

Comment: @andreymal Fetch API не всеми браузерами поддерживается https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch Но если Вы добавите пример реализации на Fetch API, то это не будет лишним.

Comment: Для IE11 есть полифилл, остальные поддерживать нет смысла :) (а мне писать ответ лень)

Comment: @andreymal ну.. Писать комментарии Вы же находите время :) Тем более, что с Fetch API реализовать это ещё проще.